# Apply CSS to td with html loaded into it via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Afternoon, I have a table in which i use .load to load a html page into a td, i apply css (specifically translateZ via  .class td{} to apply to the td's) which moves the td backwards, but the td contents stay where they are, Any help appreciated.

```
<table id="newsfeed_table2" class="newsfeed_table2">
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>

    .newsfeed_table2{
transform-style: preserve-3d; 
perspective:500px;
    padding: -100px; margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    translatez(-110px);
    left: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}
table.newsfeed_table2 td{
transform-style: preserve-3d; 
perspective:500px;
    padding: -100px; margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
   top: 350px;
   translatez(-110px);
   left: 400px;
   width: 300px;
```

}

And i load it with  $('#id').load("xxx",function()   {});

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: You can help yourself by taking a few minutes to read [ask]. We can't guess at what your code looks like or why it doesn't work as expected. Also review [mcve]

Comment: You must post your code otherwise it will be difficult to get help

Comment: added the relevant source code

Answer (score 2):

I think it's syntactically wrong to begin with, change:

> `translatez(-110px);`

to:

> `transform:translateZ(-110px);`

If you want that animated, add this:

> `transition: transform 1s ease-in;`

We can't go by much with info given, but try that first.

Comment: "We can't go by much with info given, " really? I gave you all the code that actually applied. thanks for the transform suggestion but i copy pasted the css from where it worked in other places in my project, its not the translation that isnt worrking alone its any css i try apply to the table doesnt get applied to the inner html, should i just cycle through all elements in the innerHTML and use .addClass induvidually?

Comment: --The incomplete jQuery you provided doesn't even match what's in the DOM. --I don't see any element with `id="id"`.--`"xxx"` is that a real location? --Read [`transform: translateZ()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ). --"in the `innerHTML` makes very little sense, `innerHTML` is a JavaScript method, it's not an element, document, or window having a location in DOM. --`.addClass()` to what? And to what ends, sir? Frankly you are not clear as to 1. what's the problem, 2. what you've tried already.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `transition` property to your elements which says that they should do some animation.
Example:

```
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

This will enable all kind of transitions (including future transitions)

Comment: im not trying to animate it, xP, that comes later when i attach it to a scroll event, and translate doesn't inherently require transitions

Comment: @SamSmith oh ok. can you make a snippet or run it in jsbin or something? can help you better knowing exact issue. didn't quite get the problem